# Azure Pipeline with SpringBoot and Gradle failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, gradle, pipeline

Hi I Run a Snyk security analysis in a Azure pipeline and I get the following error below, I tried to search for a solution but could not find any. What could be? Below you can find the error and my pipeline.yaml

```
 > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.6.
 Required by:
     project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.1.6
  > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.6 
 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.5' but:
      - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.6 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11
          - Other compatible attribute:
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
      - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.6 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
          - Other compatible attributes:
              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
              - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
      - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.6 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11
          - Other compatible attribute:
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
      - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.6 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 11
          - Other compatible attribute:
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
      - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.6 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 11
          - Other compatible attribute:
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
      - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.6 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
          - Other compatible attributes:
              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
              - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
```

This is my pipeline cong yaml, looks like I set up correctly the jvm but yet in the logs of the jobs running I see a gradle jvm 11:

```
   variables:
   - name: projectName
    value: 'reports'
   - name: jdkVersion
    value: '17'
   - name: GIT_COMMIT_ID
    value: $(Build.SourceVersion)
   - name: SNYK_API
    value: https://app.eu.snyk.io/api/
   trigger:
    branches:
     include:
     - master

 resources:
   repositories:
  - repository: azure-pipelines-templates
    type: git
    name: "name/azure-pipelines-templates"
    ref: refs/tags/v10

 pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

 steps:
  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ComponentVersion]$(./gradlew -q :printVersion)"
  displayName: Get Component Version

 - template: gradle/gradle_ci.yaml@azure-pipelines-templates
   parameters:
    jdkVersion: $(jdkVersion)
    sonarServiceConnection: 'sonarCloud.service.connection'
    sonarProjectKey: 'reports'
    sonarProjectName: 'expense-reports'
    containerRegistry: 'docker.registry'
    containerRegistryUrl: 'registrysharedinternalapps.azurecr.io'
    dockerRepository: $(projectName)
    dockerTag: $(ComponentVersion)-${{ variables.GIT_COMMIT_ID }}
    skipTests: false
    codeCoverageToolOption: none
    useGradleToBuildDockerImage: false
    dockerBuildAndPush: true
    testTasks: build
    snykSkip: false
    snykServiceConnectionName: 'snyk_eu_service_connection'
    snykOrgUrlName: 'openwt-internal-projects'
    snykTasks:
    - snykFailOnIssues: false
    snykAdditionalArguments: '-d --all-projects -exclude=build.gradle'
    - snykFailOnIssues: false
    snykTargetFile: 'build.gradle'
    snykProjectName: 'expense-report'
    snykAdditionalArguments: '-d'
```

Comment: Your pipeline uses Java 11, Spring Boot 3.x require at least Java 17.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks fro the reply. Where can I set it to Java 17? I added to the post my pipeline conf.

Comment: Someone with more azure knowledge needs to answer that, apparently you are also using some templates so not sure what is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you **@M. Deinum** for your comments:-

Refer my [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77981694/set-up-jvm-version-in-azure-agent-for-pipeline/77985534#) to install **`Java version 17`** as **`ubuntu-latest`** Microsoft hosted agent for ***Azure Devops does not support Java version above 11 by default.***

**My yaml code:-**

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '17'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

  - script: |
      echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to JDK 17 location."
      java -version
    displayName: 'Check Java Version'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Your updated **`yaml code`** will look like this with **`JavaToolInstaller@0`** task:-

```yaml
variables:
  - name: projectName
    value: 'reports'
  - name: jdkVersion
    value: '17'
  - name: GIT_COMMIT_ID
    value: $(Build.SourceVersion)
  - name: SNYK_API
    value: https://app.eu.snyk.io/api/

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: azure-pipelines-templates
      type: git
      name: "name/azure-pipelines-templates"
      ref: refs/tags/v10

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '17'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

  - script: |
      echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to JDK 17 location."
      java -version
    displayName: 'Check Java Version'

  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ComponentVersion]$(./gradlew -q :printVersion)"
    displayName: 'Get Component Version'

  - template: gradle/gradle_ci.yaml@azure-pipelines-templates
    parameters:
      jdkVersion: $(jdkVersion)
      sonarServiceConnection: 'sonarCloud.service.connection'
      sonarProjectKey: 'reports'
      sonarProjectName: 'expense-reports'
      containerRegistry: 'docker.registry'
      containerRegistryUrl: 'registrysharedinternalapps.azurecr.io'
      dockerRepository: $(projectName)
      dockerTag: $(ComponentVersion)-${{ variables.GIT_COMMIT_ID }}
      skipTests: false
      codeCoverageToolOption: none
      useGradleToBuildDockerImage: false
      dockerBuildAndPush: true
      testTasks: build
      snykSkip: false
      snykServiceConnectionName: 'snyk_eu_service_connection'
      snykOrgUrlName: 'openwt-internal-projects'
      snykTasks:
        - snykFailOnIssues: false
          snykAdditionalArguments: '-d --all-projects -exclude=build.gradle'
        - snykFailOnIssues: false
          snykTargetFile: 'build.gradle'
          snykProjectName: 'expense-report'
          snykAdditionalArguments: '-d'
```