# Set up JVM version in Azure agent for pipeline

Tags: java, azure, gradle

even tough I set up the jdk version to 17 in my azure-pipeline.yml still in the logs i see that the jvm is 11 when running the pipeline. How can I change it?

Logs from pipeline:

```
Gradle 8.5


Build time:   2023-11-29 14:08:57 UTC
Revision:     28aca86a7180baa17117e0e5ba01d8ea9feca598

Kotlin:       1.9.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          11.0.22 (Eclipse Adoptium 11.0.22+7)
OS:           Linux 6.2.0-1019-azure amd64
```

and this is my azure pipeline.yml:

```
     variables:
       - name: projectName
       value: 'reports'
       - name: jdkVersion
       value: '17'
       - name: GIT_COMMIT_ID
       value: $(Build.SourceVersion)
       - name: SNYK_API
       value: https://app.eu.snyk.io/api/
     trigger:
      branches:
       include:
         - master

     resources:
       repositories:
         - repository: azure-pipelines-templates
       type: git
       name: "name/azure-pipelines-templates"
       ref: refs/tags/v10

     pool:
       vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
      - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ComponentVersion]$(./gradlew -q :printVersion)"
      displayName: Get Component Version

    - template: gradle/gradle_ci.yaml@azure-pipelines-templates
    parameters:
    jdkVersion: $(jdkVersion)
    sonarServiceConnection: 'sonarCloud.service.connection'
  sonarProjectKey: 'OpenWebTechnologyFoundry_expense-reports'
  sonarProjectName: 'expense-reports'
  containerRegistry: 'docker.registry'
  containerRegistryUrl: 'registrysharedinternalapps.azurecr.io'
  dockerRepository: $(projectName)
  dockerTag: $(ComponentVersion)-${{ variables.GIT_COMMIT_ID }}
  skipTests: false
  codeCoverageToolOption: none
  useGradleToBuildDockerImage: false
  dockerBuildAndPush: true
  testTasks: build
  snykSkip: false
  snykServiceConnectionName: 'snyk_eu_service_connection'
  snykOrgUrlName: 'openwt-internal-projects'
  snykTasks:
  - snykFailOnIssues: false
    snykAdditionalArguments: '-d --all-projects -exclude=build.gradle'
  - snykFailOnIssues: false
    snykTargetFile: 'build.gradle'
    snykProjectName: 'expense-report'
    snykAdditionalArguments: '-d'
```

Where should I check to set up the jvm? I am not familiar with azure pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Blog](https://dev.to/jflamy/compiling-java-17-using-maven-in-an-azure-devops-pipeline-24cn), The **`ubuntu-latest`** Azure DevOps agent that you're using does not include JAVA version above 11. Thus According to this  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124946/how-to-you-use-a-specific-version-of-java-in-azure-devops-agent-without-download) by Martin Kreidenweis and pallxk, You need to use  **`- task: JavaToolInstaller@0`** to install JDK 17 which will be set as **`JAVA_HOME`** path,

*Refer my Azure DevOps yaml code below:-*

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '17'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

  - script: |
      echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to JDK 17 location."
      java -version
    displayName: 'Check Java Version'
```

***Output:-***

[image]

***You can implement this in your code like below:-***

```yaml
variables:
  projectName: 'reports'
  jdkVersion: '17'
  GIT_COMMIT_ID: $(Build.SourceVersion)
  SNYK_API: 'https://app.eu.snyk.io/api/'

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '17'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

  - script: echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to JDK 17 location."
    displayName: 'Set JAVA_HOME to JDK 17'

  - script: |
      java -version
      echo "JVM: $(java -version)"
    displayName: 'Check Java Version'

  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ComponentVersion]$(./gradlew -q :printVersion)"
    displayName: Get Component Version

  - template: gradle/gradle_ci.yaml@azure-pipelines-templates
    parameters:
      jdkVersion: $(jdkVersion)
      sonarServiceConnection: 'sonarCloud.service.connection'
      sonarProjectKey: 'OpenWebTechnologyFoundry_expense-reports'
      sonarProjectName: 'expense-reports'
      containerRegistry: 'docker.registry'
      containerRegistryUrl: 'registrysharedinternalapps.azurecr.io'
      dockerRepository: $(projectName)
      dockerTag: $(ComponentVersion)-$(GIT_COMMIT_ID)
      skipTests: false
      codeCoverageToolOption: none
      useGradleToBuildDockerImage: false
      dockerBuildAndPush: true
      testTasks: build
      snykSkip: false
      snykServiceConnectionName: 'snyk_eu_service_connection'
      snykOrgUrlName: 'openwt-internal-projects'
      snykTasks:
        - snykFailOnIssues: false
          snykAdditionalArguments: '-d --all-projects -exclude=build.gradle'
        - snykFailOnIssues: false
          snykTargetFile: 'build.gradle'
          snykProjectName: 'expense-report'
          snykAdditionalArguments: '-d'
```